# linking file menu items to buttons

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, menu, interface-builder

I'm in need of linking some buttons in a 'document based' application to the file menu (bold text, italic text, make text bigger etc.). The issue is that since its a document based application, the MainMenu.xib is a completely different XIB file than the MyDocument.xib, so I can't drag the connections in Interface Builder like I usually would. Does anyone have a workaround? Is there a way to link button actions to a separate XIB files' built in menu functions?

Zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you use the `First Responder` place-holder object.

[About the First Responder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW16)

> "In Interface Builder, the First Responder is a proxy object that represents the first object in your application’s dynamically determined responder chain. Because the responder chain of an application cannot be determined at design time, the First Responder proxy acts as a stand-in target for any action messages that need to be directed at the application’s responder chain. Menu items commonly target the First Responder proxy. For example, the Minimize menu item in the Window menu hides the frontmost window in an application, not just a specific window, and the Copy menu item should copy the current selection, not just the selection of a single control or view. Other objects in your application can target the First Responder as well."

Also see:
[Connecting Menu Items Across Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW32)

Also, if you want to create buttons whose actions are basically the same as the Format > Bold, etc. commands, see: [Connecting the Font Menu in Interface Builder 3](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2007/qa1571.html)

Comment: thanks - so can anyone provide any insight on how to use that for linking between menu.xib and mydocument.xib?

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I'm still having a hard time following. The documentation assumes I'm editing the MainMenu.xib, and I'm not. The menu items work fine, I just need 'shortcuts', if you will, to those items in MyDocument.xib.